# Does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point;

Tags: c#

I've done a bit of looking around, and no one's been able to answer this. I have a static main void and it looks like it should be working.

Compiler:

```
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        string Output = "Out.exe";
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Properties.Resources.source);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {
                WinBody.Text = 
                            "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                            ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                            ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Successful Compile
            MessageBox.Show("yay");
        }
```

source.txt

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1.
/// </summary>
class HelloWorldClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error on this? I really don't understand. This same code works on my other projects.

Comment: Same error. Still not working.

Comment: @SamIam There is no requirement in C# that `Main` be public.

Comment: @user3818701 Have you tried setting the `MainClass` property of your `CompilerParameters` instance to `HelloWorldClass`?

Comment: Assuming you've pasted your code correctly for source.txt - looks like you're missing the last close brace for the namespace.

Comment: Adding the extra } at the end of sources via the provided `Compiler` code it did work. This was under VS2013

Comment: Up until now it seems there is an assumption that this the problem is in sources.txt (with the exception of the missing closing brace). However I'd like to see the OP update the question so he provides some source code that shows how he defined `main` in the **Compiler** code. I am thinking that it hasn't been declared properly there. In essence I am guessing his Compiler code isn't compiling and he hasn't even got to the point of running his application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code.. I have tried it. If you replace your `Properties.Resources.source` with the actual code you've provided - you'll note there's a compiler error. The issue therefore is your resource. Double check that.

That said, there is a property called `MainClass` that you can apply to the `CompilerParameters`. This lets you choose where your entry point will be.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.mainclass(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you Check All the Open Parenthesis were Closed, I can see one is missing at the end for namespace... And also check if you have any other Main() class declared in other classes...

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you must set the closing brace of namespace. Your source must look like:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Summary description for Class1.
   /// </summary>
   class HelloWorldClass
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler would throw an error ... you're correct, but the error is before that part.

Comment: Replace the resource for the source text, and try again, if the problem is an exception could you give me the message and the line?

Answer (score 0):

Your source.txt file is incorrect (not sure if it was pasted incorrectly into stack overflow). Should be:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>

    class HelloWorldClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
// Add missing bracket
}
```

Your Compiler code snippet doesn't include the actual main entry function, but I tried your code in my own application as is. I created a WPF C# application (WpfApplication2), added `source.txt`, Added a `WinBody` Textbox to the main window and used the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            string Output = "Out.exe";
            System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Properties.Resources.source);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                {
                    WinBody.Text +=
                                "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                                ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                                ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Successful Compile
                MessageBox.Show("yay");
                //Run App
                Process.Start(Output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code inside `MainWindow()` after `InitializeComponent()` is taken almost verbatim from the OP's code snippet. The exceptions being `WinBody.Text =` was changed to `WinBody.Text +=` so that multiple error messages are concatenated; I run the compiled application at the end with `Process.Start(Output);` to verify it prints `Hello World!`. It successfully runs and prints `Hello World!`. If I use the OP's source.txt with the bracket missing I don't get 'yay' (which is correct) and the Textbox has this error: "Line number 15, Error Number: CS1513, '} expected;" which is what one would expect.